# iPad Simulator Multitouch Cursors Don't Show Up When Window is Scaled 100%

Tags: iphone, ipad, simulator, iphone-sdk-3.2

I have the iPhone SDK 3.2 installed and been working on an iPad application. However, the iPad simulator doesn't show the two gray multitouch "cursors" when I hold down the ALT/OPTION button and move the mouse around. This only happens when the simulator scale size is set to 100%. If I have it set to 50% they show up. When I have it set to be an iPhone, they show up. It's only iPad 100% size. The multitouch still works fine, I just can't see where I'm "touching".

I've trying closing the simulator completely, changing from the iPhone and back again. Resizing. All sorts of stuff. Has anyone else seen this problem? Anyone have any suggestions for fixing this? I've googled and searched SOF for anyone else having this problem, but I kinda wonder if it's just me.

If it makes a difference I have a Mac Mini 1.83 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo with Snow Leopard 10.6.3 installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the sim, it has been in all of the beta's as well as the GM seed. Nothing you can do.